# python file opening in wrong folder

Tags: python, windows, random, python-3.5, dice

I am making a dice roll program and I have a problem. I have 2 folders in my program: "dice roll", and "dice". dice roll has dice inside of it. dice roll also has a python file called dice roll.py:

```
from random import randint
exec(open("./dice/DiceCrop.py").read(), globals())
print(randint(1,6))
```

The dice folder has a python file called DiceCrop.py:

```
from PIL import Image

dice = Image.open("dice.png")

dice1 = dice.crop((0, 50, 65, 150))
dice1.save("one.png")

dice2 = dice.crop((64, 50, 131, 150))
dice2.save("two.png")

dice3 = dice.crop((130, 50, 196, 150))
dice3.save("three.png")

dice4 = dice.crop((196, 50, 262, 150))
dice4.save("four.png")

dice5 = dice.crop((262, 50, 328, 150))
dice5.save("five.png")

dice6 = dice.crop((328, 50, 394, 150))
dice6.save("six.png")
```

The dice folder also has an image file "dice.png". However, when I run dice roll.py it says there is no such file as "dice.png". I know why this happens, but I don't know how to fix it. It happens because it opens in the dice roll folder and not the dice folder. How do I make it open in the dice folder and not the dice roll folder? Here is the error message:

[image: error message]

Comment: When you execute the code from the DiceCrop.py file inside the dice roll.py file, it uses the file path in DiceCrop.py. But since dice roll.py is executed in a different folder than the png files, it fails to find them. You should just put everything in the same folder or look into `import` in python to handle relative imports such as this one.

Comment: Why on Earth do you do `exec(open("./dice/DiceCrop.py").read()...`??? If you really need to use that file, `import` it.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Dyz's suggestion:

**`DiceCropy.py`**:

```
from PIL import Image

def create_dice():
    dice = Image.open("dice.png")

    dice1 = dice.crop((0, 50, 65, 150))
    dice1.save("one.png")

    dice2 = dice.crop((64, 50, 131, 150))
    dice2.save("two.png")

    dice3 = dice.crop((130, 50, 196, 150))
    dice3.save("three.png")

    dice4 = dice.crop((196, 50, 262, 150))
    dice4.save("four.png")

    dice5 = dice.crop((262, 50, 328, 150))
    dice5.save("five.png")

    dice6 = dice.crop((328, 50, 394, 150))
    dice6.save("six.png")
```

**`roll.py`**:

```
from random import randint
from .DiceCrop import create_dice
import os

if not os.path.exists('one.png'):
    create_dice()
print(randint(1,6))
```

What the above does is to use the DiceCrop.py file as a python **module** that exposes the `create_dice` interface.  You can then reuse the `create_dice` function in other python files as needed.  We also added a quick test to make sure we weren't recreating the dice images on every run.  Good luck!